# Capture analytics from Facebook Open Graph "like" button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Does anyone know of how to capture from Facebook analytics around the use of the "like" button--i.e., if I've got thousands of pages with the Like button on them, how to query Facebook to see how many likes each of them has received? Is there a Facebook API call for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[It's on their open graph documentation page here under "Programmatically administering your pages".](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph)

Just do a GET on "https://graph.facebook.com/?id={URL}"

Example they provide:

> ```
> https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/
> ```

Returns some json:

```
{
   "114324145263104": {
      "id": "114324145263104",
      "name": "The Rock (1996)",
      "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-sf2p/hs252.snc3/23275_114324145263104_2071_s.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/",
      "category": "Movie",
      "fan_count": 328
   }
}
```